# Zoo Visitor: Members unable to update profile on front end

Tags: members, forms, zoo-visitor

I have a profile edit page where members should be able to update their content. The superadmin account has no problems only members. Unfortunately when they try to update the form is submitted and then they see the error in the attached screenshot.
[image]
In my form I’ve explicitly set require_password=“no” but this problem is persisting.
Below is the code from my form.

```
  {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form return="/profile/success" require_password="no"}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Info</legend>

      <label for="EE_email" class="form-label">Your login email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-text" value="{username}" />

      <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="member_firstname">{label:member_firstname}</label>
          <input type="text" name="member_firstname" id="member_firstname" value="{if member_firstname}{member_firstname}{/if}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="member_lastname">{label:member_lastname}</label>
          <input type="text" name="member_lastname" id="member_lastname" value="{if member_lastname}{member_lastname}{/if}"/>
        </div>
      </div><!--row-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="mbr_url">{label:mbr_url}: don't forget http://</label>
            <input type="text" name="mbr_url" id="mbr_url" value="{if mbr_url}{mbr_url}{/if}" placeholder="http://cayugahospitality.com"/>
          </div>

          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="mbr_location">{label:mbr_location}</label>
            <input type="text" name="mbr_location" id="mbr_location" value="{if mbr_location}{mbr_location}{/if}"/>
          </div>
        </div><!--row-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="six columns">
            <label for="member_photo">Photo: Upload a square photo of your face. Make sure this is a .jpg or .png and no more than 2MB or 600px by 600px.</label>
            {field:member_photo}
          </div>

          <div class="six columns">
           <label for="member_linkedin">{label:member_linkedin}</label>
            {field:member_linkedin}
          </div>
        </div><!--row-->


        <label for="mbr_bio">{label:mbr_bio}</label>
        {field:mbr_bio}

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="bios">
        <legend>Cayuga Membership</legend>
        <label for="member_divisions">{label:member_divisions}</label>
        <p>Select the divisions you represent and drag them to the right side.</p>
        {field:member_divisions}

        <label for="member_clients">{label:member_clients}</label>
        {field:member_clients}

        <label for="member_projects">{label:member_projects}</label>
        {field:member_projects}

        <label for="member_testimonials">{label:member_testimonials}</label>
        {field:member_testimonials}

        <label for="member_speakers">{label:member_speakers}</label>
        {field:member_speakers}

        <div id="speakers-bio">
        <label for="member_divisions">{label:member_speakers_bio}</label>
        {field:member_speakers_bio}

        <label for="member_topics">{label:member_topics}</label>
        {field:member_topics}

        </div>

  </fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{username}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>

  {/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"When updating username, screen_name or password inside the update form providing the current password is always required except for super-admins and the parameter does not have to be specified." Source: http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/update.html

Even though the user may not explicitly be updating their username, for example, since the field appears in the form, the above will apply.

This is why I had to separate general profile information from username & password as follows:

http://cl.ly/image/2r3E123Q3o0J

Comment: If this is incorrect, or has changed in the meantime, someone please let me know. Thanks.